# Update column with data of FOR LOOP Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have the below code, I need that the output of the print update a new column.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
import urllib.parse
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
df = pd.read_csv('IR006.csv')
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

df4 = pd.read_csv('IR006.csv')
df4['UPDATE'] = "" **#This is the column where i wanna see the output of the for loop**
```

So, here is the loop that fetch data from URL:

```
for link in df4.iterrows():
    url = link[1]['URL'].replace('/v01/', '/depot/')
    x = urlopen(url)
    new = x.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(new, "lxml-xml")
    match = ''.join(re.findall(r"[C][L]\S{8}", str(soup)))
    print(match)
```

Output:

```
CLdbDQgFdD
CLYwHQYDVR

CLYwHQYDVR
CLYwHQYDVR

CLYwHQYDVR
```

The Dataframe look like this:

[image: DATAFRAME]

So how I can put the data that generates the loop in a new column name "UPDATE"

Comment: `df4['UPDATE'] = df['URL'].apply(my_func)` and before that define `def my_func(x): your statements`. here x is url of every row, do whatever you want to do with it and return value

Comment: When i def the function give me this error:
----> 2 url = link[1]['URL'].replace('/v01/', '/depot/') TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: you don't need this at all. As i said, x is already url, you need to write statements after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
for idx,row in df4.iterrows():
    url = row['URL'].replace('/v01/', '/depot/')
    x = urlopen(url)
    new = x.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(new, "lxml-xml")
    match = ''.join(re.findall(r"[C][L]\S{8}", str(soup)))
    df4.at[idx,'UPDATE'] = match
```

Comment: ----> 2     url = link[1]['URL'].replace('/v01/', '/depot/')
TypeError: string indices must be integers

The code give me this error :(

Comment: @FelipeConcha the error you're getting is in your for loop. Try the edited code; if it doesn't work, I will try to debug your for loop.

Comment: @FelipeConcha, what you were doing is referencing the first element of the row and then again referencing it by column name. When you use ```iterrows```, it gives you a Series so if you reference it by position or column name, it should directly give you the value. 'Idx' just refers to the index of the iterator.

Comment: It was essentially ```row[1]['URL']``` vs ```row['URL']```.

Comment: u know how can i set that only update where the row is empty or "", df4.at[idx,'UPDATE'] = match ???

Comment: Just add an if condition at the end: ```if row['UPDATE'] == "": ```